# Adding noise function to a channel model

Tags: unetstack

I have noise function and I want to add it to my own channel model, where can I get more information about the channel model other than the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the "[Developing custom channel models](https://www.unetstack.net/channels.html#developing-custom-channel-models)" section of the developer's guide. The [`AbstractAcousticChannel`](https://www.unetstack.net/javadoc/org/arl/unet/sim/channels/AbstractAcousticChannel.html) is perhaps your best starting point. You only need to implement 4 methods to customize this class to your needs:

- `double getRxPower(Reception rx)`
- `double getNoisePower()`
- `boolean detect(Reception rx, double snr)`
- `int decode(Reception rx, double snr)`

The first two methods estimate the signal power and the noise power. The second two methods take in an SNR (signal/noise power ratio) and estimate whether the frame can be detected, and how many bit errors the frame will have.

An simple version of this customization realized by delegating some of this functionality is illustrated in "[Extending `AbstractAcousticChannel`](https://www.unetstack.net/channels.html#extending-the-abstractacousticchannel)" section.

Comment: when I run model it  shows following error    **`  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.arl.unet.sim.channels.UrickAcousticModel: method <init>()V not found `** @Mandar Chitre

Comment: @DEEKSHITHNS – Did you manage to resolve this? Seems like an incorrect constructor. I saw you have another post on this, which I responded to.

Comment: yes, the answer in the other post solved the problem, thank you, sir.